# Is it ok to ask the question: "How do you ask strangers for a model release?"

Tags: discussion

First off, I hope this is an appropriate use of the meta site.

I'm looking for guidance prior to asking, as I understand this can be a subjective question... The body of my question follows the line. Any tips on shaping it up prior to asking (or nixing it altogether) would be great.

---

**How do you ask strangers for a model release?**

I've searched google a bit, and there are some answers out there, but figured I'd ask here and perhaps we can really centralize some good techniques.

And the periphery:

- Any good "opening lines"?
- Does an electronic release vs. a paper release seem to make it easier?
- What kinds of turn downs do you get, and what are good ways of
  handling those?
- Do you offer print(s) in exchange for releases? What other terms do
  you use?

Comment: I guess I'll just take the lack of comments as a lack of concerns...

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fine as far as being on topic, but it's also been asked several times before:

[How to ask permission from a stranger to take their portrait?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8871/how-to-ask-permission-from-a-stranger-to-take-their-portrait) (marked as a duplicate of [How do I approach people for a natural look in street photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/610/how-do-i-approach-people-for-a-natural-look-in-street-photography))

and

[How should I approach people to take their portrait?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25040/how-should-i-approach-people-to-take-their-portrait)

and

[What workflow should I use for managing model releases?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17337/what-workflow-should-i-use-for-managing-model-releases)

Comment: Hah. I went through every question tagged model-release. I think that's why I missed the first several you listed. I saw the last, but thought it was well enough different to be considered its own question. I'll hold off unless others express interest in seeing the question hit the floor.